# Using for_loop to combine multiple subset datasets

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to select the same 3 variables from dflist 1-4. dflist is the list containing 4 datasets I have already loaded. i wrote a code to achieve it. My code like this:

```
dfmul<-rbind(dflist[[1]][,c("siteid_public","childid_public","round")], 
                dflist[[2]][,c("siteid_public","childid_public","round")], 
                dflist[[3]][,c("siteid_public","childid_public","round")], 
                dflist[[4]][,c("siteid_public","childid_public","round")])
```

But this looks very chunky and not efficient. Can someone help to figure out how to I simplify it? Thanks a lot~~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over your list using `lapply`, select your variables and bind all resulting rows.

```
dfmul <- do.call(rbind, lapply(dflist, "[", c("siteid_public",
                                              "childid_public",
                                              "round")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dfmul <- map_dfr(dflist, ~select(.x, siteid_public, childid_publicm, round))
```